# OpenXML: Allow editing of Content Controls in locked Word document

Tags: controls, ms-word, document, openxml

I want to create a Word document that works as a template, where all the document is locked from editing except the Content Controls (`<sdt/>` elements) in the document that the user can edit.

What I've seen is that if I lock the document edition (right now I'm using the `_markAsFinal` property) there's no way to unlock a single Content Control.

Am I missing something? Or is this by design?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your settings.xml file, you'll want under `<w:settings/>` an element like this:

```
<w:documentProtection w:edit="forms" w:enforcement="1" w:cryptProviderType="rsaFull"
    w:cryptAlgorithmClass="hash" w:cryptAlgorithmType="typeAny" w:cryptAlgorithmSid="4"
    w:cryptSpinCount="100000" w:hash="UrgUnH3e8g+JF+pZ0azudEQQUYY=" 
    w:salt="dKkOT11EOm/O3alLt8NBbQ=="/>
```

The hash and salt you'll need to set on your own, you can refer to the [Ecma specs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/dev_center/ms-devcentlp/51a0d3ff-9f77-464c-b83f-2de08ed28134) and [implementation notes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/office_standards/ms-oi29500/e12d2773-e2d0-45bf-b1c2-b8f0548e156d) for those details, but [this is a really good tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/vsod/how-to-set-the-editing-restrictions-in-word-using-open-xml-sdk-2-0) to just jump right in. But what this does is limit all editing to *only* content controls.